# Unable to determine what CMake generator to use. Please install or configure a preferred generator, or update configuration settings

Tags: c++, cmake

I just want to be able to compile/run my OpenGL C++ projects on my local machine.

- Do I need "nRF Connect" if I'm only pursuing local projects?
- I have VS Code installed running version 1.71.0 (user setup) on Windows_NT x64 10.0.22000
- I am using the mingw64 compiler located in C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe
- My active kit is GCC 12.1.0 x86_64-w64-mingw64 that is displayed on the bottom faceted pane in the window
- I have my "CMakeList.txt" generated with the corresponding "main.cpp" file using the "CMake: Quick start" tool
- When I run the "CMake: Build" tool, I get the error "Unable to determine what CMake generator to use". Therefor my CMake "build" directory is never created in my $(workspace)

I have tried running the "CMake: Reset" tool and I don't think that is the problem right now. In my "settings.json" file at the bottom, I see "nrf-connect.toolchain.path: " setting is set to the value "PATH". I think that is one of the issues but don't know what value to change it too. Also my environment variable "Cmake: Configure Environment" located in settings->Extensions->CMake Tools is empty for my key/value pair, also don't know what to add to that as well. I've been combing the internet for weeks so I can articulate my problem to you guys which as much of it solved before I brought the issue here. I was able to compile/run my C++ projects on VS code with no issue prior to installing CMake but am trying to build projects with OpenGL. And from what I seen CMake is one of the options that is required when it comes to building OpenGL projects.

Don't send me some documentation as a solution because I tried it and that is why I'm here. It blows my mind that there isn't a step by step on how to integrate CMake with OpenGL in VS code. The tutorials I've seen, they skip a lot of crucial steps which is the dumbest thing I have ever seen and it leaves us pulling our hair out.

[CMake: Configure Environment setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CdAL.png)

Comment: At a guess you don't have make or ninja available on your path. Cmake only generates build files, you need something else to do the actual building

Comment: Is there a reason you're using vscode rather than visual studio? The latter is much easier to setup for beginners and comes with everything you need pre installed

Comment: Did you try to explicitly specify [the generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html) using the `-G` command line option? This may yield a error message mentioning requirements of using the specific generator.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I like vscode because of its lightweight compatibility and like the environment more the VS. And wdym I need something to do the actual building? Isn't that the whole point of my g++ compiler, to build my project? Tell me what I need to install. What key/pair values should I put for my CMake configure environment?

Comment: You need to install make or ninja

Comment: Check your folder where msys is installed. In there navigate to the \msys64\mingw64\bin\ folder. The make file is not named as make, rather is named as mingw32-make. Rename this file to make. This worked for me